# Problem in creating preformatted text during editing

Tags: discussion, support

Sometimes when I'm editing posts which need preformatting (mainly code pre formats), If I click on the {} icon on editing tools tab:

[image]

I can't achieve the effect I want, instead the text appears to be just indented and not preformatted as a block. I have noticed this frequently 
with lengthy paragraphs which need to be formatted as code. Inline preformatting works fine with  `` .

How can I create a preformatted block of text during editing? For example I was trying to edit this post: [Tasker to programmatically uninstall apps](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/187834/209414).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post that you wanted to edit looked like this:

---

This is what I got so far, it might not be the most efficient way to do it.

- I run the following command via Termux Task plugin.

> pm list packages >/storage/emulated/0/Apps.txt
>   diff --unchanged-line-format= --old-line-format= --new-line-format='%L' /storage/emulated/0/BaselineApps.txt /storage/emulated/0/Apps.txt | sed 's/^[^:]*://' >/storage/emulated/0/NewApps.txt

- Read file NewApps.txt to variable %Apps

---

I suggest, instead of using whitespaces in every line, use `<pre>` and `</pre>` at the beginning of first line and end of last line.

E.g.

`<pre>`

```
LINE1
LINE2
```

`<pre>`

If you're editing the text which falls between a list, simply add one whitespace before `<pre>` to align the whole preformatted text with the list. E.g.

---

This is what I got so far, it might not be the most efficient way to do it.

- I run the following command via Termux Task plugin.

  ```
  pm list packages >/storage/emulated/0/Apps.txt
  diff --unchanged-line-format= --old-line-format= --new-line-format='%L' /storage/emulated/0/BaselineApps.txt /storage/emulated/0/Apps.txt | sed 's/^[^:]*://' >/storage/emulated/0/NewApps.txt
  ```
- Read file NewApps.txt to variable %Apps

Comment: Now that is a perfect answer! thanks

Comment: Instead of the `<pre>` you can also use 3 back-ticks on separate lines (i.e. 3 before and 3 after). Usually you can follow the introductionary 3 by the format, e.g. `html`, to have syntax highlighting – but that doesn't work on all SE sites.

Comment: @Izzy thanks for the input

Answer (score 2):

Oh my, I just found the solution:

[image]

So the solution is **indenting the target text by eight spaces**

It seems my issue was that I was trying **to create preformatted block within a list**.

For related markdown this article also helps, [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). They also state another way of doing this;
Highlighting target text and pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>